# Jump from one spreadsheet to another using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which only works when I am in the current sheet where the code is being run.
In A1, I have a checkbox whose job is to refresh api requests. So my code below clicks on the checkbox and fetches new data. So the purpose of my code is basically to click on the checkbox in A1. However, running this code only activates the checkbox but doesn't fetch the new results if I am not in the target spreadsheet. However, the moment I enter the target spreadsheet, the checkbox becomes actually "active" and not just checked.
Important to mention that I use SyncWith Addon to fetch requests and it's the one placing the checkboxes in A1 for fetching new results. So my code is just to click on the checkbox inside A1.

If I am on a different sheet and run the code, it doesn't work. I have tried to use `setActiveSheet()` but it doesn't work. If my code can switch/jump spreadsheet tabs then that's sorted.

Screenshot of what I mean by jumping from Spreadsheet to current
[image]

TO:

[image]

```
function clear_paste_run() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID");
var sheet = s.getSheetByName("Test");
sheet.getRange("A1").clearContent();
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
cell.setFormula('=TEXT(NOW(),"HH:MM")'); 

var ssss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID");
var sheetSs = ssss.getSheetByName("Test");
var AG1val = sheetSs.getRange('B1').getValue(); // get the value of B1
sheetSs.getRange("B2").setValue(AG1val); // set the value of B1 to B2

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID");
  var ssheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  var testrange = ssheet.getRange('B2');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
 
 //Run Nov
  if ( testvalue == '120') {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID");

SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[5]);
spreadsheet.getRange("A1").check();
 }
```

Comment: Your current script is the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet which is not the Spreadsheet of `thespreadsheetID`. Under this situation, you want to move from the current active Spreadsheet to the specific sheet of another Google Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I used the ```thespreadsheetID`` which is the Workbook spreadsheet id. Maybe I shouldn't use workbook id because the app script code is running in the same workbook anyway? Not sure.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to move between the sheets to other sheet in the same Google Spreadsheet, please modify `SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID")` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`. By this, you can move the sheet. But when you want to move between the sheets in the current active Spreadsheet to other sheet in the different Google Spreadsheets, this cannot be directly achieved.

Comment: Running into some weird behavior. The suggestion above works BUT only when I manually run the code. I am using a trigger to run the code every 1 minute. So when the condition if ( testvalue == '120') {} is met, the code appears to run in the background and instead doesn't visit tab as supposed to. But manually executing the code works perfectly. Not sure why this is so.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I am using a trigger to run the code every 1 minute.`, from your question, I couldn't notice that you are trying to run the script with the time-driven trigger. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. When you are trying to run the script by the time-driven trigger, unfortunately, this cannot be used. I think that the time-driven trigger might work without opening the browser. It seems that this is the current specification. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: It's okay, I wasn't clear. If it's not possible to do this with time driven trigger is there any way to achieve this with code maybe? The time driven trigger doesn't seem to switch tabs. If I can manage this through some code will still be fine. The approach doesn't matter, as long as it works really.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understand that when you don't use the time-driven trigger, the script works. How about this? If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Without the time-driven trigger yes it works but I have to manually click Run. I want to automate this. Some code to automate the function to run every 1 minutes will be the ideal solution because time-driven trigger won't work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, it is required to use the workaround. And, the workaround uses the sidebar and the dialog. Are those included in your goal? Unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual goal. So I asked about this. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Please don't apologize your English is better than mine! Yes, I am fine with the workaround. How is it done?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Yes, I am fine with the workaround.`, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to move from the current sheet to the specification sheet in the same Google Spreadsheet.
- And, you want to run this script every 1 minute.

When you want to move from the current sheet to the specification sheet in the same Google Spreadsheet, your script is required to modify as follows.

#### From:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID")
```

#### To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
```

But when you want to run this script every 1 minute, unfortunately, this cannot be achieved using the time-driven trigger. So in this case, it is required to use a workaround. When this workaround is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

This sample script uses the sidebar.

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet as a script.

```js
// Please run this function.
function openSidebar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"));
}

function clear_paste_run() {

    // do something
    // When you want to use your script, please modify `SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID")` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

}
```

##### HTML and Javascript side: `index.html`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Spreadsheet as HTML.

```html
<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="start">
<input type="button" onclick="stop()" value="stop">
<script>

let run;
const runGoogleScript = _ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withFailureHandler(reject).withSuccessHandler(resolve).clear_paste_run());
const main = _ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(async () => await runGoogleScript().then(resolve).catch(reject), 60000));

async function start() {
  run = true;
  console.log("Start.")
  while (run) await main();
  console.log("End.")
}

function stop() {
  run = false;
}
</script>
```

##### Testing.

When you run `openSidebar`, a sidebar is opened on Google Spreadsheet. And, when you click "start" button, the script is run. In this case, the function of `clear_paste_run` is run every 1 minute. When you use your script by modifying from `SpreadsheetApp.openById("thespreadsheetID")` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, the sheet is moved.

#### Reference:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: This solution worked! Grateful.

Comment: @Dan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I closed the file and left it to run but it stopped after I closed it. So this means the code will switch tabs as long as you have the document open. I thought this would work too even if it's closed. Was almost there but maybe it's not possible?

Comment: @Dan This workaround uses Javascript on the sidebar. So, unfortunately, when the browser is not opened, this workaround cannot be used. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study more and more. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: But it's surely the closest thing I could get so forever grateful.