# Alert box on click link google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am very new to all of this, and I just wanted to know if it's possible to have an alert box every time someone is clicking on a link in my google doc, I have the script so that an alert pops up every time you open the doc, but I want another one every time you click on a link, no specific, just all the links in the doc.

Comment: I don't think that there is a specific trigger for clicking on links

Comment: Okay thank you :/ I guess the alert box when opening is enough for what I want ^^

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, OnSelectionChange and OnEdit triggers cannot be used with Google Document. In my answer, I proposed a workaround for indirectly achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a text of hyperlink on Google Document is clicked, you want to open a dialog as an alert.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, OnSelectionChange and OnEdit triggers cannot be used for Google Document. So, it is required to use a workaround. At this time, I remembered [my recent post](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/12/01/pseudo-onedit-trigger-for-google-document-using-google-apps-script/). I thought that when this workaround is used, your goal might be able to be indirectly achieved. In this answer, I would like to propose a workaround.

This workaround uses Javascript. And, the pseudo OnEdit trigger is achieved using Javascript. So this workaround uses a sidebar.

#### Sample script:

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste this script to the script editor of Google Document as a script file.

```js
function openDialog() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const cursor = doc.getCursor();
  if (!cursor) return;
  const ps = cursor.getElement();
  if (ps.getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) return;
  const link = ps.asText().getLinkUrl();
  if (!link) return;
  const text = `<p>This is a text with a hyperlink.</p><p>The link is <a href="${link}" target="_blank">${link}</a></p>`;
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text).setWidth(350).setHeight(100), "sample");
  Utilities.sleep(5000); // Please adjust this value for your actual situation.
}

// Please run this function.
function openSidebar() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setTitle("Sample"));
}
```

##### Javascript & HTML side: `index.html`

Please copy and paste this script to the script editor of Google Document as a HTML file.

```html
<input type="button" onclick="start()" id="b1" value="start" />
<input type="button" onclick="stop()" id="b2" value="stop" disabled />
<script>
  let run;
  const runGoogleScript = (_) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withFailureHandler(reject).withSuccessHandler(resolve).openDialog());
  const main = (_) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(async () => await runGoogleScript().then(resolve).catch(reject), 1000));

  const start = async () => {
    const b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
    const b2 = document.getElementById("b2");
    b1.disabled = true;
    b2.disabled = false;
    run = true;
    console.log("Start.");
    while (run) console.log(await main());
    console.log("End.");
    b1.disabled = false;
    b2.disabled = true;
  };

  const stop = (_) => (run = false);
</script>
```

#### Testing:

Please run `openSidebar`. By this, the sidebar is opened. And you can use this script by clicking "start" button. The demonstration movie can be seen in the following GIF image.

[image]

#### References:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- Related thread.

  - [Jump from one spreadsheet to another using Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70165584/7108653)
  - [Pseudo OnEdit Trigger for Google Document using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/12/01/pseudo-onedit-trigger-for-google-document-using-google-apps-script/)