# Preserving offsets for fragments after manual document edition by user in google docs using apps script for purpose of placeholder replacement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a `google script` with offsets of given `google docs` fragments saved in variables.

**Is there any way to auto update those offsets if the user edits the document manually?**

My aim is to be able to show the user HTML form to update the placeholders within the document at the same time allowing the user to manually edit the same document. The problem that I encounter is that while the placeholders are replaced I need to save offsets of injected content to be able to update those fragments again in case users changes data input in the form. Unluckily said offsets becomes depreciated if user makes any manual modification to the document content.

In another words what I am looking for is marking fragment of text, to be able to find that fragment later, irrespective of the changes that users makes to another fragments of the document.

Comment: Sorry, there is no onEdit() trigger for Google Docs.

Comment: In your situation, as a workaround, are these threads useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70268746 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70169768/7108653 and [Pseudo OnEdit Trigger for Google Document using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/12/01/pseudo-onedit-trigger-for-google-document-using-google-apps-script/)