# Create Custom Dialog Box to Find Hyperlink and Go to that position on google doc with AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a 200 pages long google document containing some complex data like tables, paragraph and hyperlinks.
I am trying to create a custom dialog box or button with two option "next" and "Previous".
So Whenever I click on "next" it should set my cursor on next hyperlink in google doc for example if I am on page 30 and there is hyper link on page 31 too I want to jump over next hyperlink or position.

So far I am able to get all hyperlink through out the document but I don't how to set my cursor over those word or jump over to next or previous hyperlink by clicking on button in dialog box.

code.gs

```
function highlightLink3() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  const body = doc.getBody()
  const text = body.getText();

  const words = [...new Set(text.split(/[\n ]/g).map(e => e.trim()).filter(String))];
  words.forEach(t => {
    let word = body.findText(t);
    while (word) {
      const e = word.getElement();
      
      const start = word.getStartOffset();
      if (e.getLinkUrl(start)) {
        
      doc.setCursor(e.getLinkUrl(start))
      }
      word = body.findText(t, word);
    }
  });
  
}
```

So far I am able to get all hyperlink through out the document but I don't how to set my cursor over those word or jump over to next or previous hyperlink by clicking on button in dialog box.

Comment: `doc.setCursor(e, start)` should move your cursor. Regarding the jumping, you need an UI to do that. See [Jump from one spreadsheet to another using Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70169768/16125139).

Comment: @what you mean by UI could you give demo I tried this way but data fluctuating from html service to apps script code.

Comment: @finally I figure it out how to do it.. took me whole 4 hours ;(

Comment: @codingWars since you mentioned that you found the answer I think it would be good if you could post your final code here with an explanation so that any other person that has the same question can find the correct answer, that way you can contribute to the community and help others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I created a while back.  If constructs a tree view of my document based on the Headers.  I create a side bar and can navigate down the tree.  When I click on an item it directs me to that header.

My Document was 93 pages so I developed this to navigate back and forth.  Otherwise you would have to return to the table of contents every time to go to another section.

[image]

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  var thisMenu = DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Test');
  thisMenu.addItem('Treeview in Code.gs', 'treeViewOnOpen').addToUi();
}

function treeViewOnOpen() {
  try {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_TreeView");
    html = html.evaluate();
    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in treeViewOnOpen: "+err);
  }
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function TreeNode(level,name) {
  this.parent = null;
  this.level = level;
  this.name = name;
  this.children = [];
  this.link = null
}

function ToCListItem(level,text) {
  this.level = level;
  this.text = text;
  var time = new Date();
  this.link = "h"+level.toString()+"_"+time.getTime().toString();
}

function getTreeView() {
  try {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var bod = doc.getBody();
    var pars = bod.getParagraphs();
    var root = new TreeNode(0,"Root");
    var parent = root;
    var level = 1;
    var last = null;
    for( var i=0; i<pars.length; i++ ) {
      var par = pars[i];
      var head = getHeading(par);
      if( par.getText().trim() === "" ) continue;
      if( head > 0 ) {
        var node = new TreeNode(head,par.getText());
        var link = par.getLinkUrl();
        if( !link ) {
          var time = new Date();
          node.link = "h"+head.toString()+"_"+time.getTime().toString();
          par.setLinkUrl(node.link);
        }
        else {
          node.link = link;
        }
        if( head > level ) {
          parent = last;
          level = head;
        }
        else if( head < level ) {
          while( head <= level ) {
            parent = parent.parent;
            level = parent.level;
          }
          if( level === 0 ) level = 1;
        }
        node.parent = parent;
        parent.children.push(node);
        last = node;
      }
    }
    var s = "";
    for( var i=0; i<root.children.length; i++ ) {
      s = s + stringify(root.children[i]);
    }
    return s;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in getTreeView: "+err);
  }
}

function stringify(tree) {
  try {
    var s = ""
    if( tree.children.length > 0 ) {
      s = "<li><input class='node' type='button' value='+'>"+tree.name+"\n";
      s = s + "<ul>\n";
      for( var i=0; i<tree.children.length; i++ ) {
        s = s + stringify(tree.children[i]);
      }
      s = s + "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    }
    else {
      var s = "<li class='link' id='"+tree.link+"'><input class='link' type='button' value=' '>"+tree.name+"</li>\n";
    }
    return s;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function getHeading(par) {
  try {
    var head = par.getHeading();
    if( head == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1 ) {
      return 1;
    }
    else if( head == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2 ) {
      return 2;
    }
    else if( head == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3 ) {
      return 3;
    }
    else if( head == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4 ) {
      return 4;
    }
    else if( head == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5 ) {
      return 5;
    }
    else if( head == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING6 ) {
      return 6;
    }
    return -1;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in getHeading: "+err);
  }  
}

function linkClick(link) {
  try {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var bod = doc.getBody();
    var pars = bod.getParagraphs();
    for( var i=0; i<pars.length; i++ ) {
      var par = pars[i];
      var head = getHeading(par);
      if( head > 0 ) {
        if( par.getLinkUrl() == link ) {
          var pos = doc.newPosition(par.getChild(0),0);
          doc.setCursor(pos);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in setCursor: "+err);
  }
}
```

HTML_TreeView

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS_TreeView'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="tree">
      <?!= getTreeView(); ?>
    </ul>
    <?!= include('JS_TreeView'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS_TreeView

```
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: small;
  }
  
  ul.tree li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
  }

  ul.tree li ul {
    display: none;
  }

  ul.tree li.open > ul {
    display: block;
  }

  ul.tree li input {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 25px;
  }

  ul.tree li input:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding: 0 .1em;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .2em;
  }
</style>
```

JS_TreeView

```
<script>
  function expandClick(e) {
    try {
      var parent = e.target.parentElement;
      var classList = parent.classList;
      if(classList.contains("open")) {
        classList.remove('open');
        var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
        for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
          opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
        }
        e.target.value = "+";
      } 
      else {
        classList.add('open');
        e.target.value = "-";
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
  
  function linkClick(e) {
    try {
      var id = e.target.id;
      if( id === "" ) id = e.target.parentNode.id;
      google.script.run.linkClick(id);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
  
  (function () {
    try {
      var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree input.node');
      for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        tree[i].addEventListener('click', expandClick);
      }
      var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree li.link');
      for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        tree[i].addEventListener('click', linkClick);
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment but this code is not working. does not showing any think on screen

Comment: You set the text as a Header, level 1, 2, 3 etc. That determines which tree branch.  Then you.  I have it set to a menu option through onOpen.  Pick the menu option and it will display the tree in a sidebar.  I've included an image of my doc.

Comment: I doubt that your script is not gonna work if hyperlink appear in middle of any line or sentence